# Eclipse Java application can't find resources

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I have a splash screen for an an application that I am making. It is a `JWindow` with a `JPanel` and a `JLabel` I then have an `ImageIcon` on the `JLabel`. The `ImageIcon` is loaded from an `InputStream` using `this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("GenericApp.png");`. My code for the splash screen is below:

```
final JWindow window = new JWindow();
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("GenericApp.png");
Image image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(is);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
window.add(jp);
jp.add(l);
window.setBounds(500, 150, 300, 200);
window.setVisible(true);
try{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
window.setVisible(false);
```

When I launch my project, I get a blank JWindow with the dimensions I set.

Comment: So, what's the package of the class returned by `this.getClass()`, and where did you put the png file? Any exception? What's the stack trace?

Comment: there is no stacktrace because IconImage doesn't give one. The output of `this.getClass` is: `class iamthethomas.artint.CreateJFrame`

Comment: the png file is in the same package as CreateJFrame.

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) `window.setBounds(500, 150, 300, 200);` should best be `window.pack(); /* size window to image */ window.setLocation(500,150);`

Comment: ok. How do I not block the EDT?

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem: _Don't_ `sleep()` on the EDT; _do_ see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: *"How do I not block the EDT?"*  Again.. *"See Concurrency in Swing for details **and the fix."***  If you're expecting to be spoon fed solutions, you've come to the wrong place.

Comment: Do you get proper looking data to your InputStream?

Comment: @milez *"Do you get proper looking data to your InputStream?"* If not, the `e1.printStackTrace();` should be pretty informative on the matter..

Comment: I will read the Concurrency thing later, I am not at my computer.

Comment: I read the article on swing timers. I need some way to get the make the main program wait for the JWindow to be done to start. Should I just create the main program's JFrame in the timer's action listener?

Comment: I have been trying different things. Nothing works. The InputStream gives no error. I am working on implementing a timer.

Comment: I posted the solution.

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem Why not post your solution as *answer* to your own question? I'd give it an upvote ;) And having it as *answer* will show the entry as answered in searches, etc.

Comment: just did it! (stupid character counter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

Apparently, the image takes a while to load. I was calling `Thread.sleep(5000)` before it finished loading the image and thus cutting off the display process. The moral of the story is that you almost never want to use `Thread.sleep()` **USE TIMERS INSTEAD**.

Regards,

Thomas